# MySQL RAND() from a range of latest entries (ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1) – Is this possible?

Tags: mysql, random

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I would like to show a random entry from the latest posts in four categories.

I've tried combining `RAND()` with `ORDER BY contentID DESC LIMIT 0,1` but that doesn't work:

```
SELECT cc.pageID, cc.contentID, cc.contentTitle, cc.contentDate, cc.contentImage, cc.contentText, cs.pageName, cs.pageLabel_".$lang." AS pageLabel, cs.pageImage, ca.authorImage 
FROM cheeseus_content cc 
JOIN cheeseus_sections cs ON cc.pageID = cs.pageID 
JOIN cheeseus_authors ca ON cc.contentAuthor = ca.authorID 
WHERE cc.pageID IN (18, 19, 20, 21) 
ORDER BY RAND(), cc.contentID DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Is what I'm looking for possible and how?

Comment: what's the meaning of  'doesn't work'? throw error or can not wanted result?

Comment: @navylover, `ORDER BY RAND(), cc.contentID DESC LIMIT 0,1` returns just a random result from the four categories. `ORDER BY cc.contentID DESC, RAND() LIMIT 0,1` returns only the latest one among them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution I came up with. It relies on PHP instead of MySQL but does the job.

I put the IDs of the categories from which I want the latest entry in an array. Then use `foreach` to execute the required queries. After that I put the query results into a multidimensional array. Outside the `foreach` loop, I use `array_rand` to get a random ID from the multidimentional array elements. Then select the query results from the randomly chosen subarray.

```
// random entry from latest translations from four categories
$transPagesArray = array(18, 19, 20, 21);
foreach($transPagesArray as $transPagesID) {
    $latestTransQuery = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT cc.pageID, cc.contentID, cc.contentTitle, cc.contentDate, cc.contentImage, cc.contentText, cs.pageName, cs.pageLabel_".$lang." AS pageLabel, cs.pageImage, ca.authorImage FROM cheeseus_content cc JOIN cheeseus_sections cs ON cc.pageID = cs.pageID JOIN cheeseus_authors ca ON cc.contentAuthor = ca.authorID WHERE cc.pageID = ".$transPagesID." ORDER BY cc.contentID DESC LIMIT 0,1");
    $latestTransQuery->execute();
    $latestTransArray[] = $latestTransQuery->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
// choose one random entry from the latest entries array
$randomTrans = array_rand($latestTransArray);
$latestTrans = $latestTransArray[$randomTrans];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running MySQL 8 or later, you may use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT cc.pageID, cc.contentID, cc.contentTitle, cc.contentDate,
           cc.contentImage, cc.contentText, cs.pageName,
           cs.pageLabel_".$lang." AS pageLabel, cs.pageImage, ca.authorImage,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cc.pageID ORDER BY RAND()) rn
    FROM cheeseus_content cc
    INNER JOIN cheeseus_sections cs ON cc.pageID = cs.pageID
    INNER JOIN cheeseus_authors ca ON cc.contentAuthor = ca.authorID
    WHERE cc.pageID IN (18, 19, 20, 21)
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY cc.contentID DESC` should be `ORDER BY RAND()` I believe.

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7.31. My hosting company does not offer v. 8. Can the above be modified to work on v. 5.7?